# Is there a slash command to mute (or squelch) a player in Diablo 2?

Tags: diablo-ii

When playing Ladder games without a password, the game gets the same few spammers joining, spamming, leaving, and rejoining every few minutes. What I'd really like is to be able to stop them from joining at all, but I don't think that's possible. I know I can squelch them from the party window, but I was hoping there was a / command to do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/squelch <*account name>` or `/ignore <*account name>` will squelch or mute players, respectively.

Comment: Wow... guess I shoulda just tried it out. I tried /help but that gave me nothing, so I basically gave up on slash commands. 

That's also cool that you can ignore by account.

Comment: How do you exactly do that? I mean, if player's account name is, for example, Spammer123, I need to write 1): /ignore Spammer123, 2):  /ignore *Spammer123 , or maybe 3):  /ignore <*Spammer123> ? I tried to mute someone, but it seems either not working for me or I do it incorrectly :(

Comment: @Kusavil it's `/ignore Spammer123`

Comment: What does * in answer stands out for then? Why: /squelch <*account name>, instead just /squelch <account name>? I remember that we used to write * sometimes if we were referring to account, instead to players name, is it really not needed? Or maybe both versions work?

Answer (score 7):

Along with **/ignore** and **/squelch**, two great new features for combating spammers were introduced in patch 1.13d.

> - Ignoring players is now saved between sessions of the game. All ignores are now written out to disk (file: '**ignorelist**'). This feature can be toggled by issuing the command '**/ignorepersist**'.
> - Users can now filter messages based on content by issuing the command '**/filtermsg [content]**'. To unfilter content issue the command '**/unfiltermsg [content]**'. (The maximum length of a filter pattern is 128 characters)

This means there is a file called ***ignorelist*** in your Diablo 2 game directory.  Every user and message you choose to ignore/filter will be saved here.  You can even find community generated and maintained ignore lists which can be copied and pasted into the file.

Answer (score 2):

I have been suggested to use the level limit in order to prevent spambots to join games as most of these will be low level characters.

`/o igw` ignores all whispers from people not on your friend list.

Try `/help o` in BattleNet chat to see more options.